# Does referencing solves the pointer problems?

Tags: pointers, memory-leaks, reference, dangling-pointer

Hi I'm very confused using references.
If we use reference instead of pointer does it solve the dangling or even memory leakage problem?

Answer (score -1):

(Thinking specifically of C/C++ here): a reference is just an *alias*, or another name for an existing object. It is usually a lot harder to create a null reference than a null pointer, so it can help solve the "dangling" problem.

Since a reference is assigned to an existing variable, it can't really contribute to a memory leak. But it is possible to have a reference to memory that has been deallocated.